# how to change color of pin for mapview iphone

Tags: iphone, dictionary

```
MyAnnotation *ann1 = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];

  ann1.coordinate =region.center;


  [mapView addAnnotation:ann1];
```

right now its purple i want red

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement MKMapViewDelegate protocol callback and set the implementing class as the map view delegate

```
- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation {

    MKPinAnnotationView *newAnnotationPin = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"simpleAnnotation"] autorelease];
    newAnnotationPin.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed; // Or Red/Green
    return newAnnotation;

}
```

Comment: thnkas and what about if i want to add 1 more red annotaion just say a distance of 5 m ahead form current point

Comment: i want to show user current location and destination... right now i can show only destination plz help me to show current location in that map  

this is my  dest code

Comment: [code]

 NSString * theAddress = [myString  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
         theAddress];
 
 //NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%g",daddr,saddr];

 //NSLog(@" GEO44 is %@",urlString);
  
 NSString *locationString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
 
 NSLog(@" GEO MAP  is %@",locationString);

[/code]

Comment: NSString * theAddress = [myString  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",
         theAddress];
 
 //NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%g",daddr,saddr];

 //NSLog(@" GEO44 is %@",urlString);
  
 NSString *locationString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]] autorelease];
 
 NSLog(@" GEO MAP  is %@",locationString);

Comment: You can show user location setting the showsUserLocation property to YES.

Comment: Could you be more precise ? How do you want the message to be displayed ?