# How to change marker icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I was wonderring if there is a way to change those red pins that are used as markers. And if there is a way, how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean the red Badges used for such things as local and push notifications?

Comment: Or do you mean the red pins shown in the map? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3192650/how-to-change-color-of-pin-for-mapview-iphone

Comment: i mean red pins shown on map.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use 3 types of color pins in mapView are bellow..

1. `MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;`
2. `MKPinAnnotationColorPurple`
3. `MKPinAnnotationColorRed`

and if you want to add customview or image then you can add with programatically

also you can change pin in delegate method of `MKMapView` like bellow..

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
 MKPinAnnotationView *pinView  = (MKPinAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        pinView = [[[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID] autorelease];
        if (annotation == _mapView.userLocation) 
        {
//            pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
//            return pinView;
            return nil;
        }
        pinView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen; // you can use MKPinAnnotationColorPurple, MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = NO;

        return pinView;
}
```

and for custom image or pin, use bellow code..

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)_mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];//add any image which you want to show on map instead of red pins
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: @gabrjan see the updated answer dude.. its simple that you can add image instead of red pins on mapview.. :)