# Change map pin (color or image)

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I know this is a question asked a lot. I have been reading through many of the questions on here regarding this for a while. I was hoping someone would have a simpler way using the code I have to replace the pins on my map with an image. I am still very new to objective c.The code I have is very short and easy. Most of what I have found online to post pins to a map is very long and drawn out. I have the following classes and controllers for my map view:

**LocationsViewController.h**

```
#import "TechBookAppDelegate.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface LocationsViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>
{

    IBOutlet MKMapView *worldView;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;

}
@end
```

**LocationsViewController.m**

```
 #import "LocationsViewController.h"
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
@interface LocationsViewController ()


@end

@implementation LocationsViewController


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code


    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    CLLocationCoordinate2D wisconsin = {.latitude =  xx.xxxxxxx, .longitude =  -xx.xxxxxx};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D pennsyvainia = {.latitude =  xx.xxxxxxx, .longitude =  -xx.xxxxxx};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D nevada = {.latitude =  xx.xxxxxxx, .longitude =  -xx.xxxxxx};
    CLLocationCoordinate2D texas = {.latitude =  xx.xxxxxxx, .longitude =  -xx.xxxxxx};
    MapAnnotation *pinWI = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: wisconsin];
    MapAnnotation *pinPA = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: pennsyvainia];
    MapAnnotation *pinNV = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: nevada];
    MapAnnotation *pinTX = [[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: texas];

    [worldView addAnnotation:pinTX];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinNV];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinWI];
    [worldView addAnnotation:pinPA];


}
```

**MapAnnotation.h**

```
  #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D _coordinate;
    MKAnnotationView *mapView;
}

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

**MapAnnotation.m**

```
#import "MapAnnotation.h"
#import "LocationsViewController.h"

@implementation MapAnnotation
@synthesize coordinate = _coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        _coordinate = coordinate;
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

I have tried to implement methods similar to this:

```
 -(MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id<MKAnnotation>)annotation{.......
```

with various types of code but to no avail. Not sure what I am doing wrong. Isn't there a shorter way to do what I am thinking than this than what I have seen so far online.

I was hoping there was something similar to :

```
MapAnnotation *pinWI = [[[MapAnnotation alloc] initWithCoordinate: wisconsin] initWithPinImage:@"imagename.png"];
```

or could I implement something similar to this:
    pinWI:MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
only with a image location defined?

or something along those lines. Thanks in advance for everyones help and patience with a newbie.

**I really need to change the pin to a custom image. One coding schema I tried was this:**

```
    - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID] autorelease];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"location.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

**WORKING CODE:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{

    static NSString *AnnotationViewID = @"annotationViewID";

    MKAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKAnnotationView *)[worldView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];

    if (annotationView == nil)
    {
        annotationView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:AnnotationViewID];
    }

    annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"locations_marker.png"];
    annotationView.annotation = annotation;

    return annotationView;
}
```

Comment: As you say, there are _many_ questions (and answers) for this (on SO and in the docs).  Do you want to set the pin color or do you want to use a custom image?  _Can you give an example of one of the "various types of code" you tried in viewForAnnotation?_ Update your question with the code.

Comment: Try this out
 
It will helps to change marker icon
 
[Change Marker Icon][1]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761864/how-to-change-marker-icon

Comment: What class did you put the viewForAnnotation method in?  Is it in LocationsViewController or MapAnnotation?

Comment: @Anna after reading your post "What class did you put the viewForAnnotation method in? Is it in LocationsViewController or MapAnnotation? –" I moved everything into the LocationViewController and made a slight change in the code and it worked. thank you very much for your help. I am sure i will need it again in the very near future. I posted the code I used in LocationViewController.m up above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add the *type property(example-firstPin, secondPin,thirdPin etc)* to your custom `MapViewAnnotation` class.

```
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] init...
newAnnotation.type = @"firstPin";  // <-- set property in annotation
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
```

and in  your `- (MKAnnotationView *) mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>) annotation` method put a simple check

```
MapViewAnnotation *mvAnn = (MapViewAnnotation *)annotation;
if ([mvAnn.type isEqualToString:@"firstPin"])
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorGreen;
}
else if ([mvAnn.type isEqualToString:@"secondPin"])
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorRed;
}
else if ([mvAnn.type isEqualToString:@"thirdPin"])
{
    annView.pinColor = MKPinAnnotationColorOrange;
}
```

Comment: See the comment and code I added above. SO would not let me post it in a comment as it is to long.

Comment: @pawan please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35647839/show-dynamic-annotation-pin-in-mapview