# Show dynamic annotation pin in mapview

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am developing an app which use `MKMapView`. I have display multiple annotation in it. Now I want to display custom annotation image for pin.
I have made custom class for MapViewAnnotation.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *subtitle;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title SubTitle:(NSString *)subtitle AndCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;

@end
```

---

```
#import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation MapViewAnnotation

@synthesize coordinate=_coordinate;
@synthesize title=_title;

-(id) initWithTitle:(NSString *) title SubTitle:(NSString *)subtitle AndCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate;
{
    self =  [super init];
    _title = title;
    _coordinate = coordinate;
    _subtitle = subtitle;
    return self;
}

@end
```

I am getting multiple lat-long from api and displaying by this way:

```
[self.map_parking addAnnotations:[self createAnnotations]];
```

---

```
- (NSMutableArray *)createAnnotations
{
    NSMutableArray *annotations = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (NSDictionary *row in arrfinal) {
        NSNumber *latitude = [row objectForKey:@"latitude"];
        NSNumber *longitude = [row objectForKey:@"longitude"];
        NSString *title = [row objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *subtitle = [row objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
        NSString *rate = [row objectForKey:@"rate"];

        //Create coordinates from the latitude and longitude values
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coord;
        coord.latitude = latitude.doubleValue;
        coord.longitude = longitude.doubleValue;

        MapViewAnnotation *annotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:title SubTitle:subtitle AndCoordinate:coord];

        MKAnnotationView *av = [map_parking viewForAnnotation:annotation];
        if ([rate isEqualToString:@"0.00"])
        {
            av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker2"];
        }
        else
        {
            av.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker"];
        }
        [annotations addObject:annotation];

    }
    return annotations;
}
```

To Display annotation I am using this method reference by this link: [MKMapView: Instead of Annotation Pin, a custom view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814988/mkmapview-instead-of-annotation-pin-a-custom-view)

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
    if(annotation != map_parking.userLocation)
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"com.invasivecode.pin";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[map_parking dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil )
            pinView = [[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                       initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:defaultPinID];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        //pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        for (int i=0; i<arrrates.count; i++)
        {
            if ([[arrrates objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"0.00"])
            {
                pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker1"];
            }
            else if ([[arrrates objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"100.71"])
            {
                pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker2"];
            }
            else
            {
                pinView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"marker3"];
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        [map_parking.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }

    return pinView;
}
```

In this method `if-else` condition working good but all pin image display which was the last condition.

Comment: put you for loop out of if ( pinView == nil ). if block suppose to make reusable annotation pin only & will run only once if the pin object already exist.

Comment: @pawan thank you... your answer works http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259427/change-map-pin-color-or-image  Please put this answer in my question so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put you for loop out of

```
if ( pinView == nil )
```

if block suppose to make reusable annotation pin only & will run only once if the pin object already exist.

Comment: please help me on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36330331/route-is-not-displaying-in-map